# How to combine nested tax_query logic with other nested query logic?

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, tax-query

I use multiple custom taxonomies for my site and have successfully implemented a custom search which allows nesting of tax_query logic. However I now want to update that to include an option on searching post title so that the logic goes something like this:

Return posts where

```
 ( 
      (custom-taxonomy 'product-type' term is 'widget'
      OR post-title contains 'widget')

  AND (other-custom-taxonomy 'region' term is 'happycity' including child regions
       OR other-custom-taxonomy 'region' term is in (list of parent or grand-parent regions for 'happycity') excluding child regions)
 )
```

however though I can nest more than one tax_query it seems impossible to nest non-tax_query logic within a tax_query.

**How can I add this additional logic for post title?**

One idea: Can I access the "WHERE ..." part of the query after it's been built (but before it's been run) and preg_replace in some changes?

Comment: Are you passing arguments to WP_Query for your search results or building MySQL queries manually?

Comment: @jdm2112 I'm passing arguments to WP_Query at the moment. I'm not scared of building queries manually, as I have lots of experience with SQL, but they are likely less robust when it comes to upgrades etc so I'd rather not do that unless I have to